# In extjs4 how to set focus of textfield

Tags: extjs4, focus, textfield

I am working in extjs4. i have activation view form as-
[image]

For entering key i have taken item as-

```
{
                margin:'5 5 5 5',
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                fieldLabel: 'Enter key',
                layout: 'hbox',
                combineErrors: true,
                defaults: {
                    hideLabel: true
                },
                items: [{xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'a', name: 'a', width: 80,  allowBlank:false, margins: '0 5 0 0'},
                {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'b', name: 'b', width: 80, allowBlank: false, margins: '0 5 0 0'},
                {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'c', name: 'c', width: 80, allowBlank: false, margins: '0 5 0 0'},
                {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'd', name: 'd', width: 80, allowBlank: false, margins: '0 5 0 0'},
                {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'e', name: 'e', width: 80, allowBlank: false, margins: '0 5 0 0'}]},
```

I want to restrict number of characters in each block to 5. And after entering 5 char in first block,i want to set focus to next block automatically. So how to implement this in extjs4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add key listeners.  You will have configure your `textfield` something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    //...other props...
    name: 'a',
    maxLength: 5,
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    enforceMaxLength: true,
    listeners: {
        keyup: function(f, e) {
            if (f.getValue().length == 5)
            {
                var nextField = f.next();
                if (nextField && Ext.isFunction(nextField.focus)) {
                    nextField.focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could even `enableKeyEvents`, `maxLength`, `enforceMaxLength`, and the `listeners` to your `defaults`, if they are the same for all the fields.